# Minimal system of transcendance generators

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a field extension $L/K$. 
Why is a minimal system of transcendence Generators $E\subset L$, i.e. $L/K(E)$ algebraic,  already algebraically independant over $K$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I tried to assume a set $S:=E\setminus \{e\}$ for an $e\in E$ that, by minimality of E, can't be a system of transcencence generators, hence $L/K(S)$ isn't algebraic. But I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: Does anybody have a hint for me?